# today is their birthday or today is your birthday?

Tags: grammar

On twitter appears “today is their birthday” at the profile of the person who is getting old in the day. Why “their”? Doesn’t **their** means about **they**? Why not **your**? Or **its** birthday?

Comment: Twitter could have used "his or her", but they have opted for the less clunky "their" instead. One thing for sure, though, we would **never** use "its" in this context.

Comment: I don't agree that "his or her" is "clunky", but absolutely, 'its" should not be used. Nor should 'your" be used about a third peson.

Comment: @DavidS - I'm imagining the context of a social media feed, where three of my friends are having a birthday, and each one is labeled: _It's his or her birthday!_ I'd consider that a "clunky" way to convey the news.